# Calculating the mean of values in tables using  formulae [R]

Tags: r

I know commands like xtabs and table allow a user to do cross-tabulation

For example the following command generates a pivot table that shows the number of cars that have the same number of gears and cylinders.

```
> xtabs(~cyl+gear, data = mtcars)
   gear
cyl  3  4  5
  4  1  8  2
  6  2  4  1
  8 12  0  2
>
```

We can extend the formula so it could show the sum of the horse power for the cars in each bin

```
> xtabs(hp~cyl+gear, data = mtcars)
   gear
cyl    3    4    5
  4   97  608  204
  6  215  466  175
  8 2330    0  599
>
```

I am now wondering, is it possible to calculate the mean of horse powers for cars in each bin? for example something like this `xtabs(mean(hp)~cyl+gear, data = mtcars)`

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it with `xtabs` (which I've never used before), but to do it with the `reshape` package, one way is `cast(melt(mtcars, id = c("cyl", "gear")), cyl ~ gear, subset = variable == "hp", mean)`.

Comment: xtabs(hp~cyl+gear, data = mtcars)/xtabs(~cyl+gear, data = mtcars)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it in one line using `cast` from the `reshape` library

```
cast(mtcars, cyl ~ gear, value = 'hp', fun = mean)
```

Answer (score 7):

One interesting response that I received from r-help is as following:

```
> attach(mtcars)
> tapply(hp,list(cyl,gear),mean)
         3     4     5
4  97.0000  76.0 102.0
6 107.5000 116.5 175.0
8 194.1667    NA 299.5
>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the proper thing!!! I don't use xtabs, I just use the standard tapply, apply, lapply function since they accomplish everything. From the first time I new it must be solvable with standard tapply, and it is! Thanks.

Comment: +1 for base, but no need to attach, just use function(x) list(x$cyl,x$gear), mean) in apply statement. Attach is bad programming practice and can lead to big problems later on.

Comment: Or `with(mtcars, tapply(hp, list(cyl, gear), mean))`

Answer (score 3):

(Moving my comment to a response, so I can better edit it.)

I'm not sure how to do it with `xtabs` (which I've never used before), but here are a couple of ways of doing it using the `reshape` and `plyr` packages.

```
> x = melt(mtcars, id = c("cyl", "gear"), measure = c("hp"))
> cast(x, cyl ~ gear, mean)

> x = ddply(mtcars, .(cyl, gear), summarise, hp = mean(hp))
> cast(x, cyl ~ gear)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of calculating it is by using the aggregate() function. Although the output is not in the form of a table. (via [twitter](http://twitter.com/#!/julian_urbano/status/95167358712291329))

```
> aggregate(hp~cyl+gear,data=mtcars,mean)
  cyl gear       hp
1   4    3  97.0000
2   6    3 107.5000
3   8    3 194.1667
4   4    4  76.0000
5   6    4 116.5000
6   4    5 102.0000
7   6    5 175.0000
8   8    5 299.5000
>
```