# Working separately on different values of a variable in R

Tags: r, statistics, dataframe, plyr

I am quite amateur on R, so I hope it doesn't sound silly. Here it is:
I have a dataset that I am working on R. One of the variables (x1) has three categorical values (countrya, countryb, countryc). The dataset has many variables and observations, but I want to analyze it separately for each country. Should I prepare a dataframe, how can i do this with the given info? 
Let's say, dataset is called data;
variable is called x1;
and the values this variable takes and I want to analyze separately are countrya, countryb, and countryc. I hope this helps for the code.
Thanks...

Comment: See http://4dpiecharts.com/2011/12/16/a-quick-primer-on-split-apply-combine-problems/

Comment: Typically you would use `tapply`. For instance, to calculate the mean of variable x2 for each country: `tapply(x2, x1, mean)`.

Comment: There are a few similar questions around. For example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047124/grouping-ecological-data-in-r/10048629

Comment: possible duplicate of [R Grouping functions: sapply vs. lapply vs. apply. vs. tapply vs. by vs. aggregate vs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem which is fit for `ddply`. Assuming your data is in a `data.frame` which looks something like:

```
value  country
21897  A
213903 A
6322   B
3567   B
```

you can use `ddply`:

```
ddply(df, .(country), summarise, mn = mean(value))
```

to calculate the mean of `value` for each level of `country`.